# Can I call a Lambda Expression with multiple params for a Html Helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda, html-helper

Can I create a Code line like this one in MVC 3

```
<%=Html.CustomHtmlTag(r => r.Add("One"), r.Add("Two")...).Render()%>
```

I try to find and example but all the code was for `(r => r.Add("One"))`

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You can write complete functions with lambdas by simply putting braces.

```
r =>
{
    r.Add("One");
    r.Add("Two");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @VoidStar is correct if you get suck here is a more detailed example.

**MVC Code**

```
@Html.CustomHtmlTag(Model, x => { 
                                    Model.Add("One"); 
                                    Model.Add("Two");
                                    Model.Add("Three");
                                    Model.Add("Four");
                                }).Render()
```

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    private readonly IList<string> _values = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string value)
    {
        _values.Add(value);
    }

    public string ValuesToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",", _values);
    }
}
```

**HTML helper**

```
public static class MyMvcHelpers
{
    public static IMyClass CustomHtmlTag(this HtmlHelper helper, MyModel viewModel, Action<MyModel> action)
    {
        action.Invoke(viewModel);

        var expressionResult = viewModel.ValuesToString();

        return new MyClass(expressionResult);
    }
}
```

**Render class**

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    MvcHtmlString Render();
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public MyClass(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public MvcHtmlString Render()
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Concat("<h1>", _value, "</h1>"));
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
<h1>One,Two,Thee,Four</h1>
```